# Ubuntu freezes on intel atom

Tags: freeze, cpu, intel-cpu

I have a laptop with an intel atom `x5-z8350`, and it keeps on randomly freezing. I already disabled the cstate and turbo, but it still freezes. Any other fixes I can try?

Comment: Replace that hardware with one that works with Linux reliably is the best fix I can think of.

Comment: I can't, it's a small laptop.

Comment: I now it's a laptop and I meant to replace the entire laptop. Because there are no real fixes for what was born broken.

Comment: I asking how to fix it on the laptop I have.

Comment: As above, there are no fix to what was born broken. Any "Z" or "X" series and probably others (mostly Bay Trail and Cherry Tail) are very "Linux unfriendly". If you already applied the "cstate fix" there's nothing else to try. Support may or may not improve with newer kernels. Not likely because those families of CPUs will soon became obsolete. The situation (and the answer) will not change no matter how many dupes you post. You have what you payed for, an entry level glorified **Windows** tablet/notebook.

Comment: I understand... I will exchange it for a chromebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no fix. Hopefully, the kernel will add better support one day, but for now, the most you can do is use `cpulimit -l 50` on your browser, and hope for the best.