# Ubuntu 16.04 : Intel drivers install

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, updates, intel

first of all I'm not an expert in the sector, so I please you to be a little patient. 
I did reset the C: disk and installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTE on the pc which is a weird-o "Ollee" is all it says, (ive paid it 150 bucks brand new). It's got Intel hardware pretty much everywhere and it came with Win10. After the Ubuntu installation I had common graphic issues with video player and wifi not working. As I'm using it I'm discovering some of what I believe driver related issues, looking on the web I've found couple of links referring to an Intel program able to install all the Intel drivers needed pretty much automatically (that's what they said) but the links are now broken and i couldn't find any satisfying result on Intel's website nor Google. I kindly ask a little guidance on how to discover all of my hardware info, and directions on how to install the drivers (or any software) needed to get my pc working "properly". Here is a little lshw:

```
description: Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: vsyscall32
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 0
          size: 3852MiB
     *-cpu
          product: Intel(R) Atom(TM) x5-Z8300  CPU @ 1.44GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 1751MHz
          capacity: 1840MHz
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch epb pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms dtherm ida arat cpufreq
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Intel Corporation
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 22
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=iosf_mbi_pci
          resources: irq:0
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 22
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:297 memory:d0000000-d0ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:1000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-multimedia UNCLAIMED
             description: Multimedia controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
             version: 22
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:d1000000-d13fffff
        *-generic:0
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:0b.0
             version: 22
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=proc_thermal latency=0
             resources: irq:343 memory:d1818000-d1818fff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 22
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:296 memory:d1800000-d180ffff
        *-generic:1
             description: Encryption controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 22
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_txe latency=0
             resources: irq:342 memory:d1700000-d17fffff memory:d1600000-d16fffff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 22
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
  *-scsi
       physical id: 1
       bus info: scsi@0
       logical name: scsi0
       capabilities: scsi-host
       configuration: driver=usb-storage
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enp0s20u1u3
       serial: 16:09:01:00:64:5b
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.09.9 duplex=half link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
  *-network:1
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 38:a2:8c:a7:57:0f
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723bs ip=192.168.1.5 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

PS: I do really like to study from UNIX systems but being not able to watch a tutorial or having to stay linked to the ADSL through ethernet and either restarting my pc every 15 minutes is really frustrating, I'm only aiming to sort out the basic problems to get my Pc fully functional to enjoy the work I do on it. (I have no intention to switch OS nor PC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Cherry Trail processor which is a close cousin to Bay Trail I believe. In any case you are likely suffering from the Bay Trail bug which can be fixed by editing the grub boot loader configuration using:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line containing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

Add a space and `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` after `splash` and before the closing double quote.

Save the file and exit the `nano` editor.

Run `sudo update-grub`

Reboot.

Others with your Atom processor didn't have any luck though: [Ubuntu freezes on intel atom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/945446/ubuntu-freezes-on-intel-atom)

I'm hoping this common solution will work for you though. Search in Ask Ubuntu using `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` for lots of examples.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues with my house prodesk 600 g2 mini 64bit. Mainly the wifi adapter. I searched my service tag # on hp.com/support. Was told I had the realtek wifi/BT adapter. So I searched for hours and got nowhere. I finally took the cover off the SSD out and looked at the card. It was intel. So I did a simple search of my driver's and added "for Linux" to my search. I found a hosting site the exact driver's. Installed the driver's did a apt-get update/upgrade and restart. Works perfect now!

Comment: Thank you too for the help, WinEnuuchs2Unix had me researching about few issues related my drivers and i just discovered my hardware is kind of buggy(like the Bay Trail) with many os , windows as well. I reinstalled Ubuntu including updates with the installation an that helped. I solved the major problems anyway.